# Replacing trim pots with potentiometers?

Tags: audio, preamp, guitar-amplifier

I have been looking at and considering building the following circuit from Beavis Audio Research.  Their explanation of the circuit:

> Around 1965, Marshall introduced a few amps built around an 18 Watt
>   EL84 powered circuit. While these models were intended for practice,
>   the sound was much better than other small amps. Unfortunately, only a
>   few hundred of these combos were manufactured over the next three
>   years. These rare amps were given the model numbers 1958 for the 2X10"
>   combo, 1973 for the 2X12" combo, and 1974 for the 1X12" version. 
>   After hearing the sound samples there, we decided to give this circuit
>   a try as a distortion stompbox with FETs in place of the tubes.  We
>   opted to recreate the normal channel. The circuit consists of only one
>   preamp stage, a volume and unique tone control setup, the phase
>   splitter and a single power stage. There is no negative feedback, so
>   distortion will be much easier to achieve. You may notice we used 8k2
>   as the value of R17 on the 18watt.com schematic. The reason for this
>   is to scale the voltages of the associated JFET to the voltages of the
>   amp. We did find that the sound was closer to the amp when we did
>   this, instead of arbitrarily choosing a value. Please feel free to
>   experiment with this resistor on your own.

---

[image: Original Schematic]
In the schematic, there are 2 trim pots...  One for the preamp stage and one for the phase splitter stage.  I understand these are for 'set-and-forget' tuning for the circuit.

My questions are:

Should there be any issues if these trim pots were broken out off the board and replaced with potentiometers to enable adjusting from a front panel ?

What effects and/or sound changes could result from this ?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Keep the wires short and it should be fine. It's a high impedance node so it'll pick up any electrostatic interference that's going. Or you could use coax cable with +V on the screen, signal on the inner. Its capacitance will be small relative to the output low-pass filter.

Comment: Thank you, Brian.  Another question, specifically on the phase splitter stage.  Would being able to adjust that externally allow for unique sounds (basically result in "phaser" type of guitar pedals) ?

Comment: No. There isn't really a phase splitter stage in the circuit above. If there was, it would produce both +ve and -ve versions of the same signal, to drive the two output El84s. Assuming the middle FET is what's left of the phase splitter, correct adjustment of its trim is to set its gain to -1 and leave it. (The +1 output is available, unused, unlabelled, at the source). Anything else will just be yet another volume control with a minor effect on the "sound".